# How and where update specific cached counter of associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two simple models:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :offer_category

  scope :visible, -> { where(visible: true) }
end

class OfferCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offers

  def recount_visible_offers
    self.visible_offers_counter = offers.visible.count
    save
  end
end
```

I want to cache the number of visible offers in each category. Since i want to count only visible offers, i can't use Rails counter_cache. For that purpose i made a method `recount_visible_offers` on `OfferCategory`, which counts and saves what i want. But now i'm stuck on where and how to call it.

Used method need to handle these situations which all changes the counter

1. new offer is created with attribute visible=true
2. offer changes its visible attribute
3. offer with visible true is deleted
4. offer changes category

Right now it is handled with after_save and after_destroy callbacks which call `recount_visible_offers` on relevant category instance but it is rather complex and error prone given all the scenarios above. Another thing is that it is harder to test.

So i would like to change it somehow to be simpler. One idea which i have:
  Introduce method `self.recount_visible_offers` on `OfferCategory` which recounts all counters on all categories anytime any offer is changed(via callbacks again). I know its really robust but its simpler and i'm thinking dealing with performance issues when they arrive, not now when new offer is created or changed not so often and there isn't many of them.

Another way could be touch or association callbacks which i'm investigating right now.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Bonus question:**
  Where would you test that based on offer change category counters were correctly recounted? I'm not sure it belongs to unit tests since it involves 2 classes work together. On the other hand feature tests seems too heavy for this given i want to test all situations above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set it up like this:

EDIT:  this includes a slightly hacky way of keeping track of the previously associated offer category, so that the counter cache field in the old and the new can be adjusted.  I've also made it use the "changes" method to make it only do it when it needs to.

```
class Offer
  belongs_to :offer_category
  scope :visible, -> { where(visible: true) }
  attr_accessor :previous_offer_category_id

  before_update :store_previous_offer_category_id
  after_save :update_offer_category_visible_offers_counters
  after_destroy :update_offer_category_visible_offers_counters    

  def store_previous_offer_category_id
    if self.changes["offer_category_id"]
      self.previous_offer_category_id = self.changes["offer_category_id"][0]
    end
  end

  def update_offer_category_visible_offers_counter
    if self.previous_offer_category_id && self.previous_offer_category_id != self.offer_category_id
      OfferCategory.find(self.previous_offer_category_id).update_visible_offers_counter
    end
    self.offer_category.update_visible_offers_counter
  end
end

class OfferCategory
  has_many :offers

  def set_visible_offers_counter
    self.visible_offers_counter = self.offers.visible.count
  end

  def update_visible_offers_counter
    self.set_visible_offers_counter
    self.save
  end

end
```

Comment: Something similar was our first shot.. The problem is within changing category - it doesn't update the old one

Comment: ah - i see: i'll amend my answer.